# How to restart a thread when requested in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python application that reads a big table. I use `threading` to perform this task, so that GUI will not be unresponsive.
For example there is a "read table" button. If user presses this button, a new thread will start reading this table. Meanwhile, if the user presses the button again, before the previous thread was completed, I want the previous thread to abort and start again.
Is it possible in python?
I tried to set a flag and make the thread read it in regular intervals, do you think it'll be the best way? If not, what is?

Comment: Forcefully aborting a thread might be bad, and could cause resource leaks, and it might not even be possible on all platforms. Having some kind of flag to tell a thread to exit/start over is probably the most portable and safe.

Comment: Do I have to check that flag regularly? How will the thread check that flag, if it is busy with its real task (reading the table)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: Reading a table is typically done in some kind of loop. Just add a check every X iteration through that loop.

Comment: won't it slow down the application?